# Is it possible to find the index of an tuple in an array?

Tags: arrays, swift

```
Index(of: element)
```

Doesn't work for tuples, is there a way to find the index of a tuple?

Comment: let arrayOfTuples = [(1, "Hello"), (101, "World"), (200, "stack overflow")]
let firstTuple = arrayOfTuples[0].1 // Hello, by using https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1540606-subscript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use index with where clause, here a sample for a tuple with 2 members

```
let index = array.index {
    $0 == element.0 && $1 == element.1
}
```